# In Swift 4, how can you use Codable to decode JSON and create references between the decoded objects?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

How can I use `Codable` to decode JSON and cross reference the objects (not structs) as they're created? In this example I'd like the `Painting` class to have arrays of the `Color` objects also defined in the JSON. (I also want to be able to encode them back to JSON, too.)

**Bonus:** In this case I'd prefer `Painting.colors` to be a non-optional `let` property instead of  `var`. I don't want it to change after creation and I don't want it to ever be nil. (I'd rather use a default value of an empty array instead of nil.)

```
class Art: Codable {
    var colors: [Color]?
    var Paintings: [Painting]?
}

class Color: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var hex: String?
}

class Painting: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var colors: [Color]?
}

let json = """
{
    "colors": [
        {"id": "black","hex": "000000"
        },
        {"id": "red", "hex": "FF0000"},
        {"id": "blue", "hex": "0000FF"},
        {"id": "green", "hex": "00FF00"},
        {"id": "yellow", "hex": "FFFB00"},
        {"id": "orange", "hex": "FF9300"},
        {"id": "purple", "hex": "FF00FF"}
    ],
    "paintings": [
        {
            "name": "Starry Night",
            "colorIds": ["blue", "black", "purple", "yellow"]
        },
        {
            "name": "The Scream",
            "colorIds": ["orange", "black", "blue"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Nighthawks",
            "colorIds": ["green", "orange", "blue", "yellow"]
        }
    ]
}
"""


let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
let art = try JSONDecoder().decode(Art.self, from: data!)
```

Some approaches I've considered:

- [Manually encoding/decoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#2904058) the json. Seems like a lot of extra work but maybe it gives me the control I need?
- Break up JSON decoding into steps. Turn deserialize the JSON into a dictionary, pull out and decode the colors first, then the paintings (which will have access to the colors in the context). This feels like fighting against `Codable` which wants you to decode all at once using `Data`, not a `Dictionary`.
- Have `Painting` dynamically find the `Color`s at runtime via dynamic property. But I'd much rather get all the object relationships set up and  validated and then never change, before I get on with the real work. But maybe this would be the simplest?
- Not using Codable
- Some other bad ideas

Comment: I would suggest against JSON altogether. It doesn't have the (native) ability to express references.

Comment: The short answer is: JSON can't do this as a format. If you want an archiver (i.e. something more powerful than a value encoder) that serializes to JSON, currently you would need to build your own, or find someone else who has built it. It doesn't exist in stdlib. `NSKeyedArchiver` is the current Cocoa tool available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I voted to reopen your question because while it's not conveniently available with JSON and `Codable`, it can be done. You will have to decode the JSON manually so the question become: what is the least painful way to do it?

**My rule of thumb:** don't fight the JSON. Import it as-is into a Swift value and then you can do all kinds of manipulation on it. To that end, let's define a `RawArt` struct that closely follow the JSON:

```
fileprivate struct RawArt: Decodable {
    struct RawPainting: Codable {
        var name: String
        var colorIds: [String]
    }

    var colors: [Color]             // the Color class matches the JSON so no need to define a new struct
    var paintings: [RawPainting]    // the Painting class does not so we need a substitute struct
}
```

And now to transform the raw JSON object to your class:

```
class Art: Codable {
    var colors: [Color]
    var paintings: [Painting]

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let rawArt = try RawArt(from: decoder)

        self.colors = rawArt.colors
        self.paintings = rawArt.paintings.map { rawPainting in
            let name = rawPainting.name
            let colors = rawPainting.colorIds.flatMap { colorId in
                rawArt.colors.first(where: { $0.id == colorId })
            }

            return Painting(name: name, colors: colors)
        }
    }
}

class Color: Codable {
    var id: String
    var hex: String

    init(id: String, hex: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.hex = hex
    }
}

// It does not transform into the JSON you want so you may as well remove Codable conformance
class Painting: Codable {
    var name: String
    var colors: [Color]

    init(name: String, colors: [Color]) {
        self.name = name
        self.colors = colors
    }
}
```

To test that it's actually referencing a `Color` object:

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
let art = try JSONDecoder().decode(Art.self, from: data!)

art.colors[0].id = "new_black"
print(art.paintings[0].colors[1].id)    // the second color in Starry Night: new_black
```

Everything is non optional and it takes less than 20 lines of code to unarchive the object from JSON.

Comment: I had considered this approach but didn't think it would be worth the duplication. Having tried a few other approaches, I think this looks like the best one so far. Thanks for answering in the same spirit as the question was asked (and for re-opening it.)